# Vue.js 2: converting a string in a function call at an event handler

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue.js 2 I would like to convert a string into a function call so that it can be set as an event handler.
I believe this would be very practical, specially when dynamically creating lots of elements (e.g. buttons) based on a list of objects.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myArray: [
      { value: 1, fn: "firstMethod" },
      { value: 2, fn: "secondMethod" },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    firstMethod() {
      console.log("'firstMethod' was executed.");
    },
    secondMethod() {
      console.log("'secondMethod' was executed.");
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <template v-for="elem in myArray">
        <button @click="elem.fn">  <!-- Here is where I am stucked. -->
          <!-- <button> -->
          {{elem.value}}
        </button>
      </template>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My first attempt at doing this was setting the `fn` properties in `myArray` as sort of pointers to the corresponding functions with `this` (e.g. `fn: this.firstMethod`). The problem is, I believe, that at the time of the definition, these functions are still unkown, as I get: `[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined`.

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible? Is there a downside with this strategy that I am overlooking?

Comment: i don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible and in my own view this doesnt look dynamic in any way

Comment: why not just have a single function that would have a different output based on the parameter passed into the function and give those unique parameter to each object in your `myArray`

Comment: Shouldn't you write functions `fn: "firstMethod"` without the quotes? Otherwise it's a string, correct? So `fn: firstMethod` should reference the method itself. Not `this.` as this is not neccessary in the template. I would try that.

Comment: @onifadeboluwatife I agree: "dynamically" might not be the correct word. You are right, that would be a solution. The only downside with that is that, if you have lots of elements the function gets huge.

Comment: @PeterKrebs: I believe I tried the option you just mentioned, but then I get the following error message: `script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: firstMethod is not defined`

Comment: @rubebop yeah the function would get bulky ... can you give me a scenario where you would be using this approach .. let me see if i can provide a better approach

Comment: @onifadeboluwatife: thx! (Just for the record: I tried your approach and it obviously worked.) A calculator for instance.

Comment: @rubebop Oh that's right when you reference the function during creation of the `data` then the methods do not exist yet. You can stick with the solution you found. Another way I found is to override `create()` and assign the functions to-be-called there. But that's probably not self-explanatory enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create one method, which will be working with all buttons

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myArray: [
      { value: 1, fn: "firstMethod" },
      { value: 2, fn: "secondMethod" },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    basicMethod(name) {
      console.log(`'${name}' was executed.`);
      if(name === 'firstMethod') {
        //some logic, and so on for other methods if u need
      }
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <template v-for="elem in myArray">
        <button @click="basicMethod(elem.fn)">  <!-- Here is where I am stucked. -->
          <!-- <button> -->
          {{elem.value}}
        </button>
      </template>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this was the solution that @onifadeboluwatife suggested in the previous comments. It definitely works fine. The only downside is that, when having lots of elements, the function can get bulky. I also guess from the answers, that my original approach is not possible.

Comment: @rubebop for example, you can move the logic of each function into a separate file

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic method provided with the function name the call `this[ fn ]();`.

But for security reasons, you might want these custom methods to be in an object, not just on the main `this`, so other methods can't be called.

Also, you want to check if the method exists before calling it.

It would look something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myArray: [
      { value: 1, fn: "firstMethod" },
      { value: 2, fn: "secondMethod" },
      { value: 3, fn: "nonExistingMethod" }, // Won't throw an error
      { value: 4, fn: "someImportantSecureMethod" }, // Won't be called
    ],
    customMethods: {
      firstMethod: function() {
        console.log("'firstMethod' was executed.");
      },
      secondMethod: function() {
        console.log("'secondMethod' was executed.");
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    callCustomMethod(fn) {
      // Make sure it exists
      if (typeof this.customMethods[fn] === "function") {
        // Only methods inside the customMethods object are available
        this.customMethods[fn]();
      }
    },
    someImportantSecureMethod() {
      console.log('The method may not be exposed to dynamic calling!');
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <template v-for="elem in myArray">
        <button @click="callCustomMethod(elem.fn)">
            <!-- <button> -->
            {{elem.value}}
        </button>
    </template>
</div>
```

**As a side note:**
You might also considering using custom events ([see docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)) for this. Using `$emit('custom-event-name')` as the `v-on:click` handler and have your custom methods as event listeners. (Makes it easy when you later might want to make the items into separate components.)

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense (I also sort of thought of this solution, but I missed the `this[ fn ]() thing`). I also appreciate the input concerning the security aspect and lastly the idea of emitting custom events.